# XAMPP Windows Apache VirtualHost 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I had XAMPP running fine with virtual hosts on my winodws 8 machine until I was forced to restart my computer (windows update). After restarting I've noticed my virtual hosts weren't working any more. Instead of trouble shooting too much I decided to reinstall XAMPP (currently have XAMPP 3.1.0 running. Which is runnign Apache v 2.4.3)

I have my windows host file edited to redirect `sitename.localhost` to 127.0.0.1 and this is what I have in my httpd-vhost.conf:

```
 NameVirtualHost *
      <VirtualHost *>
        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
        ServerName localhost
      </VirtualHost>
      <VirtualHost *>
        DocumentRoot "C:\Users\USER\Documents\sitename"
        ServerName sitename.localhost
      <Directory "C:\Users\USER\Documents\sitename">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Every time I try to access http://sitename.localhost I get a 403 Access Forbidden error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see a VHost named _sitename.localhost_, maybe add one or add `ServerAlias sitename.localhost`

Comment: @Dehalion woops, that was the wrong httpd-vost.conf file. I've updated my original post

Answer (score 7):

Try adding `Require all granted` to the Directory configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\USER\Documents\sitename"
    ServerName sitename.localhost
    <Directory "C:\Users\USER\Documents\sitename">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, try to set reading permissions to the web site folder for **Authenticated users**.

Answer (score 2):

This will list out as index.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\USER\Documents\sitename"
    ServerName projectname.dev
    ServerAlias projectname.dev
    <Directory "C:\Users\USER\Documents\sitename">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

could you test this code pls instead of yours?

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\USER\Documents\sitename"
    ServerName sitename.localhost
   <Directory "C:\Users\USER\Documents\sitename">
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

btw, do you have index.html/php file in folder "C:\Users\USER\Documents\sitename", don't you?