# Apache 2.4.46 virtual hosts on windows 10

Tags: windows, apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

I have a virtual host configure in my httpd-vhosts.conf, and when i enable (uncommented) virtual hosts on httpd.conf and try to access localhost or any link inside local that is not configured in v-host, always show me Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

(httpd-vhosts.conf)

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName workshop.test
        ServerAlias www.workshop.test
        DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/workshop/workshop_app/public"
        ErrorLog "logs/workshop.test-error.log"
        CustomLog "logs/workshop.test-access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>
```

(httpd.conf)

```
    Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP Windows Apache VirtualHost 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448334/xampp-windows-apache-virtualhost-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 1):

Add this within your `workshop.test` vhost block:

```
<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/workshop/workshop_app/public">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I try this but the problem still there. If i use virtual hosts i'm not able to use localhost link like (localhost/phpmyadmin) always return  Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Comment: In `httpd.conf` did you set proper values for `User` and `Group`?

Comment: I don't change this things in httpd.conf, how should i configure it?

Comment: It need be your username and main group you belong to